# How can I make my page's width fixed in the mobile responsive ( HTML / CSS )

Tags: html, css

I want to make my page act just like facebook! if you try to display facebook in a mobile phone width it will stay the same as in the computer width! see the picture link :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXwru.jpg

but I want the responsive to be active for big widths ! I mean that if I display on a 1600px width computer it will fit in it the same thing for TV.
but not for mobile devices.

I have already used media queries but I want the width of mobile devices look  the same as the computer width

Comment: You're looking for css media queries

Comment: @ImmortalDude I'm already using media queries !! I don't know if you really did understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: Responsive design is based on percent widths i.e no `px` only `%`, so you should start with that, alternatively you can use a framework like bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    /*CSS if screen size >= 480px*/
}
```

You also should use the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag in the `<head>` of a page to tell mobile browsers not to change the page to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Websites like facebook is using headers to define the user device. If you see it in desktop and resize it. It does not change the view so much. But if you refresh the page it redirects you to another page `https://m.facebook.com`  so. All you have to do is to design multiple views with fixed width.